# how to loop through anchor tags in a variable using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor

I have a JS variable

```
var content = "<p><a href="http://www.wikipedia.org">WIKI</a></p>";
```

I need to add a class to the anchor tag.

Is this possible in Jquery ?

Comment: When you want to `addclass` after `append` them to `body` or `before` ?

Comment: Is your HTML string working? It should be `'<p><a href="http://www.wikipedia.org">WIKI</a></p>'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$(content).find('a').addClass('myclass');
```

Comment: this finds the anchor tag, but does not append the class to it

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Try `$(content).find('a').addClass('classToAdd');`

Answer (score 0):

sure:

```
$('<p><a href="http://www.wikipedia.org">WIKI</a></p>').find('a').addClass('foo');
```

Comment: Correct your answer ,String not working! check for `""`!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    var content = '<p><a href="http://www.wikipedia.org">WIKI</a></p>';
    $(content).filter("a").addClass("yourclassname");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Add `class` before append your `a tag`

then you should use :

**First way** :

```
var content = "<p><a class='yourclass' href='http://www.wikipedia.org'>WIKI</a></p>";
```

**Second** :

```
 var content = $("<a href='http://www.wikipedia.org'>WIKI</a>");
 content.addClass('yourclass');
 var p = $('<p></p>');
 p.append(content);
```